# How do I access external functions in a class using GroovyScript

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a simple script like this...

```
def createEntry(service){
    ...
}
class Service {
    ...
    void create(){
        createEntry(this)
    }
}
```

But when I run this code I get the following...

> hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Service.createEntry() is applicable for argument types: (Service) values: [Service@64bbfb0d]

Answer (score 0):

**Use your file name as class**.

For example your groovy file is like `filename.groovy` you can use the methods inside java class as shown below.

I hope this code will clarify your question:

```
static void m(){
    println('hai')
}

class A {

    static void a()
    {
        filename.m() // the file name you use
    }
}

A.a()
```

Comment: So lets say this is in a file called aFile.groovy. I tried aFile.m() and it didn't work just said "Exception in pipeline: No such property: aimClient for class: A <groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property:  aFile for class: Service>groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: aFile for class: A"

Comment: @JGleason The code, I shared is a example skeleton and it works well. I think, the structure you currently have in ur code is differed with what u asked in question. what is `aimClient` doing ? Please add more details in question, it helps me to understand why u getting this exception. :)

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer on the Groovy forum.

It's terrible, but at least it's possible...

```
def g = { x, y -> x * y }

class MyFunc {
   def fun
   def run(x, y) { fun(x, y) }
}

def  fn = new MyFunc(fun: g)

println fn.run(4, 9)
```